How to attach fingers to gloves for a Rig?
I have to make a Rig for a game proyect so I made some arms and gloves and deleted the hand vertices that are hidden, now I need the fingers to attach to the edge of the fingerless gloves but they are clipping from the bottom side and leaving empty space from the top. I know it's possible to have the fingers move exactly with the edge of the glove but i don't know how to make that, can anyone help me? 

Maybe the simplest would be to join the glove mesh to the hand? Or you can make sure that the glove topology is the same as the hand and use the Data Transfer modifier to transfer the vertex groups from the hand to the glove

Please share your file so that we can give a try

@moonboots I finally made it by merging the mesh of the fingers and the gloves and playing a bit with the weight paint, but thanks for offering!
